# Metamask time vs block time

Tags: web3js, metamask, gas

I am building an app using web3.
I was running some test, and something came up.
Why network's block time doesn't match with metamask time to accept transacion even when I set the "fastest" gas price?

Comment: When you say 'Metamask time' what do you mean? How does it compare with 'Network's block time'?

Comment: Metamask time = Time it take from clicking the metamask extension 'send' button to the mined block timestamp.
Block time = Timestamp difference between block X and block X-1 on etherscan.

Even though using fastest gas price (mined right away) metamask sending seem slower.

For example. Polygon network have average block time of 2-3 seconds. When submiting a transaction using metamask it takes around 15 seconds to be mined, even using high gas price.